fit the data with two type of fit combined or any one type fit, whichever is good fit
I have data x and y , want to fit one part with power_fit and other part with negative power_fit settling to zero finally and start from some -20nm with some 5nF values and goes down after that minima agian start rising and goes to zero.[]
and here is my data corresponding to the curve as shown in the figure on x-> distance;  and y --> force;


distance    force 
-1.77E-08   3.40E-09
-1.76E-08   3.40E-09
-1.75E-08   3.54E-09
-1.74E-08   5.27E-09
-1.73E-08   4.81E-09
-1.72E-08   2.07E-09
-1.71E-08   1.05E-09
-1.70E-08   4.62E-10
-1.69E-08   2.44E-10
-1.67E-08   1.82E-10
-1.66E-08   -5.28E-11
-1.65E-08   -2.64E-10
-1.64E-08   -3.22E-10
-1.63E-08   -4.37E-10
-1.62E-08   -7.34E-10
-1.61E-08   -9.50E-10
-1.60E-08   -9.78E-10
-1.59E-08   -1.02E-09
-1.58E-08   -1.10E-09
-1.57E-08   -1.13E-09
-1.56E-08   -1.21E-09
-1.55E-08   -1.17E-09
-1.54E-08   -1.15E-09
-1.53E-08   -9.42E-10
-1.52E-08   -6.11E-10
-1.51E-08   -4.80E-10
-1.50E-08   -3.50E-10
-1.49E-08   -3.29E-10
-1.48E-08   -3.02E-10
-1.47E-08   -2.56E-10
-1.46E-08   -2.32E-10
-1.45E-08   -2.24E-10
-1.44E-08   -1.78E-10
-1.43E-08   -1.31E-10
-1.42E-08   -1.35E-10
-1.41E-08   -9.99E-11
-1.40E-08   -4.09E-11
-1.39E-08   -2.26E-11
-1.38E-08   -2.88E-11
-1.36E-08   -3.43E-11
-1.35E-08   -5.07E-11
-1.34E-08   -4.52E-11
-1.33E-08   -3.59E-11
-1.32E-08   -5.06E-11
-1.31E-08   -5.36E-11
-1.30E-08   -3.86E-11
-1.29E-08   -4.83E-11
-1.28E-08   -6.97E-11
-1.27E-08   -4.58E-11
-1.26E-08   -1.40E-11
-1.25E-08   -1.74E-11
-1.24E-08   -4.76E-11
-1.23E-08   -6.25E-11
-1.22E-08   -3.08E-11
-1.21E-08   -1.74E-11
-1.20E-08   -2.85E-11
-1.19E-08   -3.00E-11
-1.18E-08   -3.10E-11
-1.17E-08   -2.50E-11
-1.16E-08   -3.61E-11
-1.15E-08   -5.81E-11
-1.14E-08   -4.96E-11
-1.13E-08   -3.37E-11
-1.12E-08   -3.30E-11
-1.11E-08   -2.93E-11
-1.10E-08   -3.62E-11
-1.09E-08   -4.94E-11
-1.08E-08   -4.43E-11
-1.06E-08   -3.83E-11
-1.05E-08   -3.11E-11
-1.04E-08   -2.48E-11
-1.03E-08   -3.75E-11
-1.02E-08   -2.31E-11
-1.01E-08   -2.24E-11
-1.00E-08   -4.04E-11
-9.92E-09   -2.70E-11
-9.82E-09   -1.43E-11
-9.72E-09   -9.88E-12
-9.61E-09   -1.54E-11
-9.51E-09   -1.96E-11
-9.41E-09   -2.28E-11
-9.30E-09   -3.71E-11
-9.20E-09   -4.11E-11
-9.10E-09   -1.74E-11
-8.99E-09   9.00E-12
-8.89E-09   1.02E-12
-8.78E-09   -2.85E-11
-8.68E-09   -1.83E-11
-8.58E-09   -1.25E-12
-8.47E-09   -1.47E-11
-8.37E-09   -3.09E-11
-8.27E-09   -3.52E-11
-8.16E-09   -3.08E-11
-8.06E-09   -3.14E-11
-7.96E-09   -4.07E-11
-7.85E-09   -4.25E-11
-7.75E-09   -4.19E-11
-7.65E-09   -2.50E-11
-7.54E-09   -1.22E-11
-7.44E-09   3.36E-12
-7.34E-09   7.60E-12
-7.23E-09   -1.82E-11
-7.13E-09   -3.02E-11
-7.03E-09   -3.79E-11
-6.92E-09   -3.27E-11
-6.82E-09   -3.25E-11
-6.72E-09   -1.24E-11
-6.61E-09   -1.16E-11
-6.51E-09   -4.27E-11
-6.41E-09   -2.73E-11
-6.30E-09   -1.81E-11
-6.20E-09   -2.86E-11
-6.10E-09   -2.55E-11
-5.99E-09   -3.75E-11
-5.89E-09   -4.72E-11
-5.78E-09   -8.01E-12
-5.68E-09   2.63E-11
-5.58E-09   1.73E-12
-5.47E-09   -3.50E-11
-5.37E-09   -4.88E-11
-5.27E-09   -4.08E-11
-5.16E-09   -1.41E-11
-5.06E-09   5.05E-12
-4.96E-09   1.13E-11
-4.85E-09   1.43E-12
-4.75E-09   -2.32E-11
-4.65E-09   -3.38E-11
-4.54E-09   -1.38E-11
-4.44E-09   9.58E-12
-4.34E-09   1.52E-12
-4.23E-09   -1.99E-11
-4.13E-09   -3.96E-11
-4.03E-09   -4.08E-11
-3.92E-09   -3.01E-11
-3.82E-09   -1.87E-11
-3.72E-09   -5.81E-12
-3.61E-09   3.56E-12
-3.51E-09   -7.76E-12
-3.41E-09   -4.15E-11
-3.30E-09   -6.75E-11
-3.20E-09   -6.22E-11
-3.10E-09   -3.56E-11
-2.99E-09   -1.90E-11
-2.89E-09   -1.76E-11
-2.78E-09   -7.10E-12
-2.68E-09   1.25E-11
-2.58E-09   8.13E-12
-2.47E-09   -8.95E-12
-2.37E-09   -1.52E-11
-2.27E-09   -1.48E-11
-2.16E-09   -1.17E-11
-2.06E-09   -2.28E-11
-1.96E-09   -4.26E-11
-1.85E-09   -5.58E-11
-1.75E-09   -4.82E-11
-1.65E-09   -3.35E-11
-1.54E-09   -1.04E-11
-1.44E-09   5.28E-13
-1.34E-09   -1.03E-11
-1.23E-09   -1.22E-11
-1.13E-09   1.52E-12
-1.03E-09   -4.77E-12
-9.23E-10   -3.37E-11
-8.19E-10   -1.84E-11
-7.16E-10   -8.62E-12
-6.13E-10   -2.80E-11
-5.09E-10   -2.48E-11
-4.06E-10   -3.99E-12
-3.02E-10   -7.42E-13
-1.99E-10   -1.86E-11
-9.54E-11   -1.71E-11
8.06E-12    1.53E-11
1.12E-10    1.91E-11
2.15E-10    -2.75E-12
3.18E-10    -7.53E-12
4.22E-10    -1.34E-12
5.25E-10    -2.12E-11
6.29E-10    -3.89E-11
7.32E-10    -2.37E-11
8.36E-10    -2.73E-11
9.39E-10    -3.20E-11
1.04E-09    -1.56E-11
1.15E-09    -9.17E-12
1.25E-09    -1.38E-12
1.35E-09    6.78E-12
1.46E-09    -4.55E-12
1.56E-09    -1.69E-11
1.66E-09    -2.19E-11
1.77E-09    -1.42E-11
1.87E-09    -2.43E-11
1.97E-09    -4.14E-11
2.08E-09    -4.16E-11
2.18E-09    -4.71E-11
2.28E-09    -4.83E-11
2.39E-09    -2.39E-11
2.49E-09    -2.05E-12
2.59E-09    -2.21E-12
2.70E-09    -2.18E-12
2.80E-09    -1.16E-11
2.90E-09    -1.97E-11
3.01E-09    -3.44E-11
3.11E-09    -6.25E-11
3.21E-09    -5.27E-11
3.32E-09    -2.01E-11
3.42E-09    -1.33E-11
3.53E-09    -3.15E-12
3.63E-09    1.46E-11
3.73E-09    1.82E-11
3.84E-09    -2.36E-12
3.94E-09    -2.48E-11
4.04E-09    -3.09E-11
4.15E-09    -3.72E-11
4.25E-09    -2.81E-11
4.35E-09    -2.56E-11
4.46E-09    -4.30E-11
4.56E-09    -6.31E-12
4.66E-09    2.11E-11
4.77E-09    -4.34E-12
4.87E-09    -9.74E-12
4.97E-09    -8.47E-12
5.08E-09    -8.08E-12
5.18E-09    -4.18E-12
5.28E-09    -6.95E-12
5.39E-09    -6.77E-12
5.49E-09    -6.60E-14
5.59E-09    -2.30E-11
5.70E-09    -4.33E-11
5.80E-09    -4.12E-11
5.90E-09    -4.53E-11
6.01E-09    -4.75E-11
6.11E-09    -4.15E-11
6.21E-09    -2.59E-11
6.32E-09    -1.65E-11
6.42E-09    -2.12E-11
6.53E-09    -1.48E-11
6.63E-09    3.70E-12
6.73E-09    1.29E-11
6.84E-09    6.49E-13
6.94E-09    -2.16E-11
7.04E-09    -3.00E-11
7.15E-09    -1.33E-11
7.25E-09    2.78E-12
7.35E-09    -4.47E-13
7.46E-09    -7.96E-12
7.56E-09    -5.61E-12
7.66E-09    -1.29E-12
7.77E-09    -5.08E-12
7.87E-09    -1.21E-11
7.97E-09    -1.63E-11
8.08E-09    -2.33E-11
8.18E-09    -3.40E-11
8.28E-09    -1.35E-11
8.39E-09    1.73E-11
8.49E-09    2.65E-11
8.59E-09    1.85E-11
8.70E-09    -6.51E-12
8.80E-09    -2.92E-11
8.90E-09    -3.74E-11
9.01E-09    -3.62E-11
9.11E-09    -2.00E-11
9.21E-09    -1.22E-12
9.32E-09    6.68E-12
9.42E-09    -1.60E-12
9.52E-09    -1.27E-11
9.63E-09    -1.28E-11
9.73E-09    -1.64E-11
9.84E-09    -2.32E-11
9.94E-09    1.41E-12
1.00E-08    1.03E-11
1.01E-08    -2.61E-11
1.02E-08    -3.74E-11
1.04E-08    -2.98E-11
1.05E-08    -4.38E-11
1.06E-08    -5.11E-11
1.07E-08    -3.31E-11
1.08E-08    -1.49E-11
1.09E-08    1.62E-11
1.10E-08    1.87E-11
1.11E-08    -4.80E-12
1.12E-08    -6.11E-12
1.13E-08    -1.79E-11
1.14E-08    -4.61E-11
1.15E-08    -4.14E-11
1.16E-08    -2.12E-11
1.17E-08    -1.47E-11
1.18E-08    7.30E-12
1.19E-08    1.94E-11
1.20E-08    3.81E-12
1.21E-08    -1.05E-11
1.22E-08    -3.00E-12
1.23E-08    -4.68E-12
1.24E-08    -1.91E-11
1.25E-08    -2.18E-11
1.26E-08    -2.93E-11
1.27E-08    -3.88E-11
1.28E-08    -2.89E-11
1.29E-08    -1.79E-12
1.30E-08    -9.21E-12
1.31E-08    -4.13E-11
1.32E-08    -3.83E-11
1.34E-08    7.81E-14
1.35E-08    2.32E-11
1.36E-08    1.91E-11
1.37E-08    -1.41E-11
1.38E-08    -4.52E-11
1.39E-08    -4.29E-11
1.40E-08    -1.96E-11
1.41E-08    1.87E-12
1.42E-08    -2.42E-12
1.43E-08    -3.57E-12
1.44E-08    7.99E-12
1.45E-08    1.07E-11
1.46E-08    1.46E-12
1.47E-08    1.09E-12
1.48E-08    -3.67E-12
1.49E-08    -2.01E-11
1.50E-08    -2.71E-11
1.51E-08    -1.40E-11
1.52E-08    -4.58E-12
1.53E-08    -9.81E-12
1.54E-08    -9.87E-12
1.55E-08    -1.00E-11
1.56E-08    2.84E-13
1.57E-08    -4.53E-12
1.58E-08    -2.27E-11
1.59E-08    -2.34E-11
1.60E-08    -6.68E-12
1.61E-08    1.49E-11
1.62E-08    1.96E-11
1.64E-08    1.25E-11
1.65E-08    -1.75E-11
1.66E-08    -4.14E-11
1.67E-08    -4.08E-11
1.68E-08    -2.94E-11
1.69E-08    -1.51E-11
1.70E-08    -3.19E-12
1.71E-08    1.06E-11
1.72E-08    2.12E-11
1.73E-08    1.87E-11
1.74E-08    8.40E-12
1.75E-08    -8.24E-12
1.76E-08    -2.34E-11
1.77E-08    -1.61E-11
1.78E-08    7.20E-12
1.79E-08    -1.10E-11
1.80E-08    -4.80E-11
1.81E-08    -4.89E-11
1.82E-08    -2.80E-11
1.83E-08    -1.12E-11
1.84E-08    -6.21E-12
1.85E-08    -1.20E-12
1.86E-08    -1.62E-11
1.87E-08    -2.54E-11
1.88E-08    -1.08E-11
1.89E-08    -1.80E-11
1.90E-08    -1.72E-11
1.91E-08    -1.18E-12
1.92E-08    6.22E-12
1.94E-08    1.54E-11
1.95E-08    4.97E-12
1.96E-08    -2.88E-11
1.97E-08    -3.05E-11
1.98E-08    -1.86E-11
1.99E-08    -3.75E-11
2.00E-08    -2.38E-11
2.01E-08    6.23E-12
2.02E-08    -6.22E-13
2.03E-08    -1.75E-11
2.04E-08    -2.90E-11
2.05E-08    -1.05E-11
2.06E-08    5.35E-12
2.07E-08    -1.20E-11
2.08E-08    -5.85E-12
2.09E-08    -2.46E-12
2.10E-08    -8.25E-12
2.11E-08    -5.34E-12
2.12E-08    -1.01E-11
2.13E-08    -1.50E-11
2.14E-08    -2.69E-11
2.15E-08    -4.15E-11
2.16E-08    -2.90E-11
2.17E-08    -2.49E-11
2.18E-08    -3.58E-11
2.19E-08    -2.03E-11
2.20E-08    1.35E-11
2.21E-08    1.69E-11
2.22E-08    -1.81E-11
2.24E-08    -4.05E-11
2.25E-08    -2.05E-11
2.26E-08    -8.54E-12
2.27E-08    -1.48E-11
2.28E-08    -4.88E-13
2.29E-08    8.96E-12
2.30E-08    9.94E-12
2.31E-08    3.10E-13
2.32E-08    -1.61E-11
2.33E-08    -2.69E-11
2.34E-08    -3.18E-11
2.35E-08    -2.66E-11
2.36E-08    -2.38E-11
2.37E-08    -2.72E-11
2.38E-08    -4.06E-12
2.39E-08    5.26E-12
2.40E-08    -2.21E-11
2.41E-08    -1.49E-11
2.42E-08    1.46E-11
2.43E-08    1.11E-11
2.44E-08    2.84E-12
2.45E-08    1.24E-11
2.46E-08    -7.15E-12
2.47E-08    -4.86E-11
2.48E-08    -4.72E-11
2.49E-08    -2.43E-12
2.50E-08    3.82E-11
2.51E-08    2.77E-11
2.52E-08    -6.25E-12
2.54E-08    -1.79E-11
2.55E-08    -3.61E-11
2.56E-08    -5.52E-11
2.57E-08    -1.51E-11
2.58E-08    2.69E-11
2.59E-08    2.58E-11
2.60E-08    1.48E-11
2.61E-08    -1.56E-11
2.62E-08    -3.23E-11
2.63E-08    -3.06E-11
2.64E-08    -1.79E-11
2.65E-08    4.83E-12
2.66E-08    1.33E-11
2.67E-08    1.52E-11
2.68E-08    1.82E-11
2.69E-08    6.90E-12
2.70E-08    -2.51E-12
2.71E-08    2.50E-12
2.72E-08    -2.29E-11
2.73E-08    -4.13E-11
2.74E-08    -6.23E-12
2.75E-08    1.65E-11
2.76E-08    -3.06E-12
2.77E-08    -3.29E-11
2.78E-08    -2.95E-11
2.79E-08    -9.03E-12
2.80E-08    -6.71E-12
2.81E-08    -7.09E-12
2.82E-08    -9.39E-12
2.84E-08    -1.40E-11
2.85E-08    -9.45E-12
2.86E-08    5.33E-12
2.87E-08    1.01E-11
2.88E-08    -7.60E-12
2.89E-08    -2.69E-11
2.90E-08    -2.05E-11
2.91E-08    -7.23E-13
2.92E-08    1.88E-11
2.93E-08    1.75E-11
2.94E-08    -1.39E-11
2.95E-08    -3.52E-11
2.96E-08    -2.50E-11
2.97E-08    1.07E-11
2.98E-08    8.93E-12
2.99E-08    -1.91E-11
3.00E-08    -1.71E-11
3.01E-08    -1.17E-11
3.02E-08    -5.79E-12
3.03E-08    -2.08E-12
3.04E-08    -1.33E-11
3.05E-08    -2.22E-11
3.06E-08    -2.02E-11
3.07E-08    -2.14E-11
3.08E-08    -2.41E-11
3.09E-08    -1.95E-11
3.10E-08    6.25E-12
3.11E-08    2.11E-11
3.12E-08    7.65E-12
3.14E-08    -8.28E-12
3.15E-08    -2.01E-11
3.16E-08    -1.25E-11
3.17E-08    3.62E-12
3.18E-08    -9.12E-12
3.19E-08    -1.79E-11
3.20E-08    -8.35E-12
3.21E-08    -9.35E-12
3.22E-08    -8.50E-12
3.23E-08    -3.26E-12
3.24E-08    -1.07E-11
3.25E-08    -1.32E-11
3.26E-08    -9.42E-12
3.27E-08    -1.13E-11
3.28E-08    -2.52E-11
3.29E-08    -4.17E-11
3.30E-08    -1.87E-11
3.31E-08    6.60E-12
3.32E-08    -2.80E-13
3.33E-08    7.08E-13
3.34E-08    7.62E-12
3.35E-08    2.31E-12
3.36E-08    -6.07E-12
3.37E-08    -2.43E-11
3.38E-08    -1.49E-11
3.39E-08    -8.58E-13
3.40E-08    -1.60E-11
3.41E-08    -2.04E-11
3.42E-08    -1.12E-11
3.44E-08    -6.96E-12
3.45E-08    -4.08E-12
3.46E-08    -5.40E-12
3.47E-08    -8.05E-12
3.48E-08    -6.10E-12
3.49E-08    -1.63E-11
3.50E-08    -2.99E-11
3.51E-08    -4.52E-11
3.52E-08    -3.63E-11
3.53E-08    1.07E-11
3.54E-08    2.01E-11
3.55E-08    -1.96E-12
3.56E-08    -5.51E-12
3.57E-08    -5.06E-13
3.58E-08    7.47E-12
3.59E-08    1.24E-11
3.60E-08    4.63E-12
3.61E-08    -8.83E-12
3.62E-08    -1.21E-11
3.63E-08    -1.02E-11
3.64E-08    -1.17E-11
3.65E-08    -1.79E-12
3.66E-08    5.54E-12
3.67E-08    1.25E-12
3.68E-08    -9.99E-12
3.69E-08    -3.20E-11
3.70E-08    -3.32E-11
3.71E-08    -1.23E-11
3.72E-08    -1.41E-11
3.74E-08    -1.15E-11
3.75E-08    8.24E-12
3.76E-08    -6.69E-12
3.77E-08    -3.20E-11
3.78E-08    -1.33E-11
3.79E-08    2.21E-11
3.80E-08    3.16E-11
3.81E-08    -1.39E-12
3.82E-08    -3.50E-11
3.83E-08    -1.23E-11
3.84E-08    7.52E-12
3.85E-08    -1.44E-12
3.86E-08    -7.22E-12
3.87E-08    -2.46E-12
3.88E-08    -6.43E-12
3.89E-08    -2.17E-11
3.90E-08    -2.15E-11
3.91E-08    -3.56E-12
3.92E-08    1.73E-11
3.93E-08    2.80E-11
3.94E-08    1.85E-11
3.95E-08    -6.95E-12
3.96E-08    -2.89E-11
3.97E-08    -2.89E-11
3.98E-08    1.82E-12
3.99E-08    3.65E-11
4.00E-08    2.87E-11
4.01E-08    1.03E-11
4.02E-08    1.69E-12
4.04E-08    -1.25E-11
4.05E-08    -1.52E-11
4.06E-08    -1.33E-11
4.07E-08    3.90E-12
4.08E-08    6.83E-12
4.09E-08    -1.43E-11
4.10E-08    -2.58E-11
4.11E-08    -2.63E-11
4.12E-08    -3.44E-13
4.13E-08    3.21E-11
4.14E-08    2.04E-11
4.15E-08    -8.35E-12
4.16E-08    -1.14E-11
4.17E-08    -4.94E-12
4.18E-08    2.18E-14
4.19E-08    -9.23E-12
4.20E-08    -2.60E-11
4.21E-08    -6.08E-11
4.22E-08    -5.02E-11
4.23E-08    8.58E-13
4.24E-08    1.44E-11
4.25E-08    8.04E-12
4.26E-08    4.00E-12
4.27E-08    2.88E-12
4.28E-08    -1.24E-12
4.29E-08    -3.44E-12
4.30E-08    -1.42E-11
4.31E-08    -1.07E-11
4.32E-08    -1.14E-11
4.34E-08    -1.76E-11
4.35E-08    -8.60E-12
4.36E-08    -6.77E-12
4.37E-08    -4.62E-12
4.38E-08    -4.86E-13
4.39E-08    9.45E-12
4.40E-08    1.82E-11
4.41E-08    1.12E-11
4.42E-08    -5.32E-12
4.43E-08    -1.70E-11
4.44E-08    -1.72E-11
4.45E-08    -1.93E-11
4.46E-08    -1.74E-11
4.47E-08    -6.17E-12
4.48E-08    -1.03E-12
4.49E-08    -6.10E-13
4.50E-08    -1.22E-11
4.51E-08    -1.97E-11
4.52E-08    -4.65E-12
4.53E-08    6.46E-12
4.54E-08    1.09E-11
4.55E-08    2.04E-11
4.56E-08    7.34E-12
4.57E-08    -1.38E-11
4.58E-08    -2.19E-12
4.59E-08    1.55E-12
4.60E-08    -1.16E-11
4.61E-08    -1.33E-11
4.62E-08    -1.63E-11
4.64E-08    -1.57E-11
4.65E-08    -5.91E-12
4.66E-08    -1.03E-11
4.67E-08    -2.33E-11
4.68E-08    -2.89E-12
4.69E-08    2.85E-11
4.70E-08    1.76E-11
4.71E-08    -2.48E-11
4.72E-08    -3.63E-11
4.73E-08    -4.27E-12
4.74E-08    -1.76E-13
4.75E-08    -1.43E-11
4.76E-08    -4.78E-12
4.77E-08    9.21E-12
4.78E-08    1.37E-11
4.79E-08    1.34E-11
4.80E-08    -2.21E-12
4.81E-08    -6.08E-12
4.82E-08    3.71E-12
4.83E-08    -9.30E-12
4.84E-08    -1.33E-11
4.85E-08    6.49E-12
4.86E-08    1.62E-11
4.87E-08    1.55E-11
4.88E-08    4.04E-12
4.89E-08    -2.08E-11
4.90E-08    -2.91E-11
4.91E-08    -1.47E-11
4.92E-08    -1.82E-12
4.94E-08    -2.56E-12
4.95E-08    -2.03E-11
4.96E-08    -3.82E-11
4.97E-08    -1.20E-11
4.98E-08    1.05E-11
4.99E-08    -9.13E-12
5.00E-08    -7.73E-12
5.01E-08    -1.22E-11
5.02E-08    -2.44E-11
5.03E-08    -1.19E-11
5.04E-08    -5.94E-12
5.05E-08    2.73E-12
5.06E-08    2.59E-11
5.07E-08    1.19E-11
5.08E-08    -2.35E-11
5.09E-08    -3.56E-11
5.10E-08    -4.46E-11
5.11E-08    -3.06E-11
5.12E-08    1.84E-11
5.13E-08    4.66E-11
5.14E-08    1.68E-11
5.15E-08    -2.04E-11
5.16E-08    -3.23E-11
5.17E-08    -3.17E-11
5.18E-08    -1.54E-11
5.19E-08    7.71E-12
5.20E-08    2.30E-11
5.21E-08    1.64E-11
5.22E-08    -4.91E-13
5.24E-08    -2.29E-11
5.25E-08    -1.78E-11
5.26E-08    -3.33E-13
5.27E-08    -1.28E-11
5.28E-08    -2.30E-11
5.29E-08    -7.40E-12
5.30E-08    1.14E-11
5.31E-08    9.05E-12
5.32E-08    8.96E-12
5.33E-08    1.40E-11
5.34E-08    -1.40E-11
5.35E-08    -4.92E-11
5.36E-08    -3.75E-11
5.37E-08    -1.77E-11
5.38E-08    1.65E-12
5.39E-08    2.45E-11
5.40E-08    2.89E-11
5.41E-08    1.77E-11
5.42E-08    -6.71E-13
5.43E-08    -1.22E-11
5.44E-08    -2.03E-11
5.45E-08    -2.08E-11
5.46E-08    -9.35E-12
5.47E-08    -4.77E-12
5.48E-08    -7.50E-12
5.49E-08    8.17E-13
5.50E-08    1.46E-11
5.51E-08    1.31E-11
5.52E-08    -3.66E-13
5.54E-08    -1.08E-11
5.55E-08    -8.47E-12
5.56E-08    -3.84E-12
5.57E-08    -1.17E-12
5.58E-08    4.88E-12
5.59E-08    2.59E-11
5.60E-08    8.57E-12
5.61E-08    -2.47E-11
5.62E-08    -2.35E-11
5.63E-08    -2.09E-11
5.64E-08    -1.26E-11
5.65E-08    -2.20E-12
5.66E-08    -1.23E-11
5.67E-08    -2.38E-11
5.68E-08    -1.09E-11
5.69E-08    -8.27E-12
5.70E-08    -1.30E-11
5.71E-08    1.19E-12
5.72E-08    1.45E-11
5.73E-08    1.07E-11
5.74E-08    -1.14E-11
5.75E-08    -2.30E-11
5.76E-08    4.44E-12
5.77E-08    2.63E-11
5.78E-08    -3.94E-12
5.79E-08    -3.63E-11
5.80E-08    -3.06E-11
5.81E-08    -1.93E-11
5.82E-08    1.17E-11
5.84E-08    1.98E-11
5.85E-08    -1.33E-11
5.86E-08    -1.51E-11
5.87E-08    -5.56E-13
5.88E-08    -3.31E-12
5.89E-08    -4.85E-12
5.90E-08    1.62E-11
5.91E-08    3.19E-11
5.92E-08    1.89E-11
5.93E-08    -4.85E-12
5.94E-08    -2.19E-11
5.95E-08    -6.70E-12
5.96E-08    1.14E-11
5.97E-08    2.02E-12
5.98E-08    1.40E-11
5.99E-08    3.04E-11
6.00E-08    1.43E-11
6.01E-08    -5.74E-12
6.02E-08    -1.15E-11
6.03E-08    -1.22E-11
6.04E-08    -1.79E-11
6.05E-08    -1.81E-11
6.06E-08    -9.81E-12
6.07E-08    -6.86E-12
6.08E-08    -7.75E-12
6.09E-08    -1.48E-11
6.10E-08    -1.11E-11
6.11E-08    4.77E-12
6.12E-08    4.37E-12
6.14E-08    -1.32E-11
6.15E-08    -1.82E-11
6.16E-08    -4.21E-13
6.17E-08    -2.63E-12
6.18E-08    -2.29E-11
6.19E-08    -2.88E-12
6.20E-08    1.69E-11
6.21E-08    -5.91E-13
6.22E-08    -1.94E-11
6.23E-08    -2.97E-11
6.24E-08    3.54E-13
6.25E-08    3.54E-11
6.26E-08    3.27E-12
6.27E-08    -2.18E-11
6.28E-08    -1.40E-11
6.29E-08    -2.73E-11
6.30E-08    -4.26E-11
6.31E-08    -1.81E-11
6.32E-08    1.79E-11
6.33E-08    1.25E-11
6.34E-08    1.17E-13
6.35E-08    -1.18E-12
6.36E-08    1.51E-11
6.37E-08    2.45E-11
6.38E-08    1.41E-11
6.39E-08    -2.22E-12
6.40E-08    -1.69E-11
6.41E-08    -2.22E-13
6.42E-08    3.71E-12
6.44E-08    -5.58E-12
6.45E-08    3.99E-12
6.46E-08    2.34E-11
6.47E-08    1.45E-11
6.48E-08    -1.44E-11
6.49E-08    -2.24E-11
6.50E-08    -2.17E-11
6.51E-08    -2.07E-11
6.52E-08    -1.45E-11
6.53E-08    -3.36E-12
6.54E-08    -1.30E-11
6.55E-08    -2.50E-11
6.56E-08    -9.35E-12
6.57E-08    -8.18E-12
6.58E-08    -1.38E-11
6.59E-08    -1.68E-12
6.60E-08    3.18E-11
6.61E-08    7.05E-11
6.62E-08    1.51E-11
6.63E-08    -3.42E-11
6.64E-08    -3.53E-12
6.65E-08    3.27E-12
6.66E-08    -1.60E-11
6.67E-08    -2.28E-11
6.68E-08    -1.30E-11
6.69E-08    -1.61E-12
6.70E-08    1.08E-11
6.71E-08    2.27E-11
6.72E-08    2.53E-11
6.74E-08    1.86E-11
6.75E-08    -5.11E-12
6.76E-08    -2.58E-11
6.77E-08    -3.24E-11
6.78E-08    -3.05E-11
6.79E-08    -1.17E-11
6.80E-08    -2.24E-11
6.81E-08    -2.59E-11
6.82E-08    -7.59E-12
6.83E-08    -2.43E-11
6.84E-08    -3.38E-11
6.85E-08    -2.73E-11
6.86E-08    -2.28E-12
6.87E-08    2.75E-11
6.88E-08    2.37E-11
6.89E-08    -8.20E-12
6.90E-08    -2.54E-11
6.91E-08    -9.12E-12
6.92E-08    5.32E-12
6.93E-08    1.25E-11
6.94E-08    1.52E-11
6.95E-08    4.42E-12
6.96E-08    2.43E-12
6.97E-08    1.68E-11
6.98E-08    -1.04E-12
6.99E-08    -3.03E-11
7.00E-08    -1.78E-11
7.01E-08    6.65E-12
7.02E-08    -9.43E-12
7.04E-08    -2.26E-11
7.05E-08    -1.14E-11
7.06E-08    -8.41E-12
7.07E-08    1.46E-12
7.08E-08    1.79E-11
7.09E-08    2.30E-11
7.10E-08    1.63E-11
7.11E-08    1.01E-11
7.12E-08    8.77E-12
7.13E-08    1.04E-11
7.14E-08    1.25E-11
7.15E-08    6.57E-12
7.16E-08    3.02E-12
7.17E-08    6.22E-12
7.18E-08    -4.24E-13
7.19E-08    -7.26E-12
7.20E-08    -3.01E-12
7.21E-08    7.25E-12
7.22E-08    3.23E-12
7.23E-08    -6.42E-12
7.24E-08    -5.01E-12
7.25E-08    -7.07E-12
7.26E-08    1.66E-12
7.27E-08    7.47E-12
7.28E-08    2.08E-12
7.29E-08    -4.36E-12
7.30E-08    -5.33E-12
7.31E-08    -1.27E-11
7.32E-08    -2.40E-11
7.33E-08    -1.40E-11
7.35E-08    -4.41E-12
7.36E-08    1.87E-11
7.37E-08    2.04E-11
7.38E-08    -9.53E-12
7.39E-08    -7.32E-12
7.40E-08    1.56E-11
7.41E-08    3.00E-11
7.42E-08    7.86E-12
7.43E-08    -9.26E-12
7.44E-08    -2.85E-12
7.45E-08    -9.55E-12
7.46E-08    -1.76E-11
7.47E-08    -2.26E-11
7.48E-08    -1.26E-11
7.49E-08    6.33E-12
7.50E-08    -8.56E-12
7.51E-08    -3.35E-11
7.52E-08    4.17E-13
7.53E-08    1.82E-11
7.54E-08    -8.64E-12
7.55E-08    -1.63E-11
7.56E-08    -1.71E-11
7.57E-08    -1.39E-11
7.58E-08    5.31E-12
7.59E-08    1.29E-11
7.60E-08    8.80E-12
7.61E-08    8.24E-12
7.62E-08    -3.81E-12
7.63E-08    -4.79E-12
7.65E-08    3.76E-12
7.66E-08    -1.27E-11
7.67E-08    -2.37E-11
7.68E-08    -9.57E-12
7.69E-08    -5.87E-12
7.70E-08    -5.71E-12
7.71E-08    5.08E-14
7.72E-08    1.49E-11
7.73E-08    9.27E-12
7.74E-08    -1.29E-11
7.75E-08    4.68E-12
7.76E-08    1.66E-11
7.77E-08    7.51E-12
7.78E-08    1.66E-11
7.79E-08    1.74E-11
7.80E-08    -1.85E-11
7.81E-08    -4.34E-11
7.82E-08    -2.88E-11
7.83E-08    -1.89E-13
7.84E-08    2.13E-11
7.85E-08    1.57E-11
7.86E-08    4.41E-12
7.87E-08    3.12E-13
7.88E-08    -8.49E-12
7.89E-08    -1.04E-11
7.90E-08    -1.26E-11
7.91E-08    -1.02E-11
7.92E-08    3.67E-12
7.93E-08    1.18E-11
7.95E-08    8.41E-12
7.96E-08    1.10E-11
7.97E-08    2.69E-11
7.98E-08    3.26E-11
7.99E-08    1.80E-11
8.00E-08    -9.04E-12
8.01E-08    -3.25E-11
8.02E-08    -3.51E-11
8.03E-08    -3.00E-11
8.04E-08    -3.35E-11
8.05E-08    -1.32E-11
8.06E-08    1.13E-11
8.07E-08    2.46E-11
8.08E-08    2.14E-11
8.09E-08    6.44E-12
8.10E-08    4.17E-12
8.11E-08    6.20E-12
8.12E-08    8.81E-14
8.13E-08    -6.71E-12
8.14E-08    -3.96E-12
8.15E-08    -1.47E-11
8.16E-08    -2.47E-11
8.17E-08    -1.13E-11
8.18E-08    9.52E-14
8.19E-08    -1.37E-11
8.20E-08    -4.01E-11
8.21E-08    -3.38E-11
8.22E-08    -3.44E-12
8.23E-08    1.71E-11
8.25E-08    2.31E-11
8.26E-08    2.10E-11
8.27E-08    2.19E-11
8.28E-08    7.37E-12
8.29E-08    -1.34E-11
8.30E-08    -1.28E-11
8.31E-08    -4.69E-12
8.32E-08    -1.33E-11
8.33E-08    -1.60E-11
8.34E-08    -1.06E-11
8.35E-08    -1.17E-11
8.36E-08    -1.24E-11



I am getting divided by zero at some points. I was using the two functions for it, one is before minima and another after minima.
def fit_data(x, y):
    # Define the model function for x <= xmin
    def model1(x, a, n, x0,ymin):
        return a / (x_adj**n) + ymin

def model2(x, b, m, xmin, y0):# Define the model function for x > xmin
    x_adj = x - xmin
    return -b / (x_adj**m) + y0
x_data = np.array(x)
y_data = np.array(y)
ymin = np.min(y_data)
xmin = x_data[np.argmin(y_data)]


Please fix your code formatting and provide a [mre].

this is the another power fit for the data rsing after the minima and long tail; here you can see : def model2(x, b, m, xmin, y0):# Define the model function for x > xmin
x_adj = x - xmin
return -b / (x_adj**m) + y0

That axis almost certainly has the wrong units. It's likely either N, or you need to multiply in a factor of 1e9.

NO UNIT ARE AS IT IS. y axis (i.e. force in nN ) and x axis (i.e. distance also in the range of nm).

@user97975, how big do you think 1e-8 nm is? Your x axis scale seems to represent things one-billionth the size of atoms. Your y-axis scale is worse. If you want to fit a model I think you would be better choosing it with physical content. Also, why would a distance be negative?

It looks like you want to fit a Lennard-Jones Potential (curve aspect and your defined model).
It also seems that units on your figure are a bit strange and such scaled variable may prevent optimization algorithm to converge properly.
import io
import pandas as pd
from scipy import optimize

data = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO("""    distance    force 
    -1.77E-08   3.40E-09
    -1.76E-08   3.40E-09
    -1.75E-08   3.54E-09
    -1.74E-08   5.27E-09
    ..."""
))

# removes initial artifact and long baseline
data = data.iloc[4:-850, :] 

# Rescale at nano scale:
data["distance"] *= 1e9
data["force"] *= 1e9

We create the LJ model:
def model(x, a, b, x0, m=12, n=6):
    return a / np.power((x - x0), m) - b / np.power((x - x0), n)

And try to adjust it to your dataset with classical LJ 12-6:
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(
    model, data["distance"], data["force"],
    p0=[1, 1, -18],
    bounds=[[0, 0, -np.inf], [np.inf, np.inf, np.inf]],
    maxfev=5000,
)
# [ 1.67417889e+09,  7.42112612e+04, -2.21518052e+01]

Or with custom exponents:
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(
    model, data["distance"], data["force"],
    p0=[1, 1, -18, 12, 6],
    bounds=[[0, 0, -np.inf, 2, 2], [np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, 20, 20]],
    maxfev=5000,
)
#[ 8.83089717e+04,  7.54137326e+04, -2.01743579e+01,  5.68482944e+00, 5.55369294e+00]

Fits are not really satisfactory and require guidance to run peacefully:

Which may indicate that your dataset does not follow a Lennard-Jones potential.
